# What value is LVM_SCROLL assigned?

Tags: winforms

What value is LVM_SCROLL assigned?

i.e. SW_HIDE is assigned to 0

Public Const SW_HIDE = 0

What value is LVM_SCROLL assigned too?

Where can this value and other constant values be found?

I program in a language called PL/B. It gives access to execute windows APIs but it does not have all the constants defined. Of course, the examples on the Web use the constant name so I have to track down the value.

I normally found these values in a file called WIN32API.TXT. It has many constant's values defined but as I found out it does not have LVM_SCROLL defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PInvoke.Net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Enums/ListViewMessages.html) will tell you:

```
 public enum ListViewMessages : int  
 {   
      LVM_FIRST = 0x1000,   
      LVM_SCROLL = (LVM_FIRST + 20)   
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try building a test application to print out the value of unknown constants:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <commctrl.h>

int main () {
    std::cout << "LVM_SCROLL = " << LVM_SCROLL << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```